# How to get Auth0's idToken in a React component or in a "normal" function in NextJs app?

Tags: next.js, auth0

I'm working on a NextJs app and I need to send the `idToken` in each backend call. Is there an easy way to implement that? Here's our app structure (extremely simplified):

We have a page:

```
/* src/pages/example/index.page.tsx */

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<ExamplePageProps> = async (
  context,
) => {
  const initialTranslations = await getTranslations(context.locale, ['example']);
  return {
    props: {
      initialTranslations,
    },
  };
};

export interface ExamplePageProps {
  ...
}

function ExamplePage(props: ExamplePageProps) {
  return (
    <MyComponent />
  );
}
```

The component looks like this:

```
/* src/pages/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.tsx */

export const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = (...) => {
  const handleClick = async () => {
    await makeBackendCall(param1, param2);
  }

  ...
  <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  ...
}
```

The backend call is here:

```
/* src/fetchers/webapi.ts */

export const makeBackendCall = (param1: string, param2: string): Promise<Response> => {
  fetch('http://some.url', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      /* *** THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO SEND idToken *** */
    }
  });
}

export const anotherCallWhichNeedsTheToken = () => {...}
export const andAnotherOne = () => {...}
/*...*/
```

How can I achieve this? So far the closest I have got is trying to fetch it in `getServerSideProps`, in the following way:

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
...
const session = getSession(context.req, context.res);
const idToken = session?.idToken;
...
return {
    props: {
      initialTranslations,
      idToken,
    },
};
```

...or more generic:

```
return {
  props: {
    initialTranslations,
    session: getSession(context.req, context.res),
  },
};
```

...but in any case I get a compiler error on `getServerSideProps`, saying something about props not being compatible (I think it's about returning a promise in `getServerSideProps` and specifying a "normal" object in component props, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

The idToken is stored in encrypted in a HttpOnly cookie which is the reason you can only read it from the backend code.

If your fetch requests are targetted at API's on the same domain as the client you don't need to pass the idToken as the cookies will be passed to the APIs automatically on each request. You can read them from the API using the `getSession` function.

If you need to get data from another domain, you could create a proxy API in nextjs and have the proxy API make the call to the other domain. That way you don't have to pass the idToken from the client, that could be handles in the proxy.